# How to use DataSourcePool in Adobe CQ5.5?

Tags: java, osgi, aem, osgi-bundle, sling

I have created a `@Component` and in that component at instance level I am doing `@Reference` DataSourcePool.

But the Class DataSourcePool is not found so my class doen't compile. I am using CRXDE Eclipse.
I have done all this by following this link.

http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/datasourcepool.html

Please See my code and snap shot.

```
package com.videojet.hiresite.database;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import com.day.commons.datasource.poolservice.DataSourcePool;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Reference;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;

@Component
@Service
public class ConnectionProvider {

    @Reference
    private DataSourcePool source;

    public Connection getConnection() throws Exception
    {
        //VideojetDatasource
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");   
        return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxxx","xxxx","xxx");

    }

}
```

[image]

**So Do I have to Add an Extra Jar in OSGi Bundle to this to work ?**

**Update**
@ Tomek Rękawek Dude When I say I'm not using Maven I mean it. I have NOT followed the whole tutorial.
This is what I am using it's CRXDE Eclipse
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
I download the Jar from here http://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/day/commons/day.commons.datasource.poolservice/1.0.10/

And I pasted it in /apps/myproject/src/testbundle/libs folder and the dependency is resolved.

Answer (score 3):

Add following dependency to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.day.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>day.commons.datasource.poolservice</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.10</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

In general, if you wonder which bundle contains a class, open the Felix Console, choose *Main* / *Packages* (relative path: `/system/console/depfinder`) and enter the full class name (like `com.day.commons.datasource.poolservice.DataSourcePool`). You'll get a `<dependency>` that you can copy & paste to your `pom.xml`.

Comment: I am not using Maven, infact I don't know how to use maven. I am using a dedicated Eclipse(CRXDE) that Adobe has provided for creating Bundles/Componenets/Templates/. It's like CRXDElite but more powerful. What should I do? Is there a link where I can download this as OSGi bundle ?

Comment: The tutorial you've linked describes how to create a Maven CQ project from the archetype, so if you followed it, you are using Maven. Find the pom.xml file in your project root and add above dependency to the `<dependencies>` section.

Comment: Please See Update ! My Problem is I don't know anything about this super advance tool called Maven ... I just don't know how to use it.. Why did evryone all of a sudden started using Maven. I think Maven is very complex with all those difficult to remember commands.